# Could you bend blood out of the body?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

We see in Avatar that Katara bloodbended (controlling another's blood inside their body, therefore you can control them) at least two people. But could you bend blood outside the body? For example if someone was bleeding on the floor, could you then bend that blood?

Answer (score 6):

There are quite a few examples of waterbenders bending solutions (and mixtures) with the aid of others in some cases:

> **Solutions**: It has been shown that waterbenders can manipulate any liquid that is partially water, or anything that contains water. For example, Katara bent the contents of the abbey's perfume vats.She used waterbending to stir and ladle stew into bowls, to spill ink out of a bowl, and to bend the water inside mud as well.

See [special techniques](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Waterbending#Special_techniques) on the wikia.

As it is, I'd like to point out that bloodbending is a misleading name. More likely it takes advantage of *all* the water stored in the body, e.g water solutions within cells as well as 'loose' in veins and other bodily ducts.

As blood (and the other liquids from the body) are mixtures and solutions they can be bent. Quite likely though is that with enough bending the liquid content would be removed from the blood separating cells (red/white cells and platelets) and liquid and anything suspended in it (sugars, salts, nutrients etc).

For more on Water Purification, see [this](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Waterbending#Waterbending_abilities_and_techniques) page on the wikia.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason to believe they couldn't bend blood out of the body the same as blood in the body.

I would think you'd have to bend the blood pretty quickly, though. I imagine it would eventually dry up because of a combination of platelets and evaporation of the plasma and water.